# Why is the iOS Simulator location moving?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, apple-maps

I am creating an Uber Clone App and I go the location of the simulator which is Apples location, and when I started the simulator the location started moving, as if someone is following a path around Apple. I haven't made it to where it can move, all my code is doing is grabbing the users location. Can anybody explain why this is happening?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the simulator menus you can select various simulated locations include a drive on the freeway or moving around the apple campus. It sounds like you have selected the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location in the iOS Simulator can move because it is being simulated by software. The iOS Simulator can simulate various locations for testing purposes. The location can be changed manually in the Debug > Location menu or programmatically through code.

If you're experiencing unexpected movement in the location, it's possible that it's being changed by an app or a test that you're running. If that's not the case, then it might be a bug in the iOS Simulator and you can try restarting it or resetting it to its default settings.